# Minimal Polynomial of a Permutation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

For a permutation $\sigma$ of the set $\{1,...,n\}$, and consider the $n \times n$ matrix $A_\sigma$, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ column is the standard vector $e_{\sigma (i)}$.

By experimenting with a few permutations I kept getting that $A^n_\sigma$ = $I$

Two Questions essentially :

Is It true that $A^n_\sigma$ = $I$ $ \; \; \forall \sigma \in S_n$

If this is true,  how would I show it?

And second is the minimal polynomial  infact $x^n-1$ for any $\sigma$  ?

Comment: Let $n=3$ and $\sigma=(12)$; then

$$A_\sigma=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}\;,$$

$A_\sigma^2=I$, and $A_\sigma^3=A\ne I$.

Comment: I see. Whoops! Intuition can be misleading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=3$ and $\sigma=(12)$; then

$$A_\sigma=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}\;,$$

$A_\sigma^2=I$, and $A_\sigma^3=A\ne I$.

More generally, the $i$-th column of $A_\sigma^k$ is $e_{\sigma^k(i)}$, so the least $k$ such that $A_\sigma^k=I$ is the order of $\sigma$ in the permutation group $S_n$. This is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles in the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$; in my example this is $\operatorname{lcm}\{2,1\}=2$. In particular, $k$ can certainly be any positive integer not exceeding $n$: just use the $k$-cycle $(12\ldots k)$. These are in general not the only possibilities, however; for example, with $n=5$ we can have $\sigma=(123)(45)$, of order $6$.

Comment: In any case the minimal poly of $A_{\sigma}$ must divide $x^{n!}-1$, which is a pretty useless bound since we know that the min poly must have degree less than $n$. Can we find an explicit expression for $m_{A_{\sigma}}$?